# MPMediaItem not casting in playing in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, mpmediaitem

I can't get an MPMediaItem to play in an AVAudioPlayer

I put all my songs in an Array

```
    let myitem = mySongs[0]
    let myURL = myitem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as! URL

    do{
        try avAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: myURL as URL)
        avAudioPlayer.delegate = self

    }
    catch{

    }
```

I get an error at the myURL line saying Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It works half of the time and the other time i get that error

If it gets past the myURL part, it fails when i try putting the URL in the AVAudioPlayer